# Add fragment to an inflated view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a `listview`. In its adapter, in the `getView` method, I inflate a view from resources. I want to add a fragment to this view. As far as I am concerned, fragments can be added to activity's view only; but this view is just created and is not attached to activity yet. How can I do it?

I also have a `<fragment>` tag in my item layout, but I can't get a reference to it, because `view.findViewById()` returns view and it cannot be cast to a `fragment`.

Comment: hmmm! why would you want to add a fragment in a custom listview?

Comment: Interesting problem. We don't have direct access to the `Activity` from an `Adapter`, do we ?

Comment: @LazyNinja This listview is complicated. It's items are some tables; table cells need some calculation for each item in list. So I want to have a tableFragment class and add it to every view of listview. I think it's the best way.

Comment: @cerebro We can have. But it won't help, I assume.

Comment: see detailed answer below. i'm looking into adding Fragments programatically from an Adapter, but its doesn`t look promising at the moment.

Comment: @MehranMahmoudi, I think  a simple class is enough not a fragment. IMO, fragments are not designed for that. If you can post the relevant source maybe we could help.